# Temporary variable destroyed with overloaded + and += operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I am getting a segfault because I believe my temporary variable is being destroyed (freeing allocated memory) before the operators are done using it. This is the code in my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Bcd b1 = Bcd(100), b2 = Bcd(20), b3 = Bcd(50);
  b3 += b1 + b2;
  return 0;
}
```

I put a print statement in the destructor and the output is as follows:

```
sum
destroying 120
sum
segmentation fault
```

I don't understand why this would occur. It appears that the temporary variable b1+b2 is being destroyed before it can be used the second time by sum. Shouldn't the temporary variable b1+b2 be valid until the end of that line in main? Did I implement the operator overloading functions incorrectly or is there some other problem with my code that I am not considering?

my custom class defined as follows:

```
class Bcd
{
 public:
  Bcd();
  Bcd(const char* num);
  Bcd(const Bcd &num);
  Bcd(const int num);
  ~Bcd();
  int getLength() const;
  Bcd& operator=(const Bcd &rhs);
  Bcd& operator+=(const Bcd &rhs);
  const Bcd& operator +(const Bcd &rhs) const;
  std::string toString() const;
private:
  //takes a character and places is at number[index]. If that index does 
  //not exist, allocates memory for that number and then sets number[index].
  void modifyNumber(char num, int index);
  char* number;
  int length;
  int size;
};
```

The important bits of the .c file is here:

```
Bcd& Bcd::operator +=(const Bcd &rhs){
  int minSize, i;
  char result[2] = {0};
  printf("sum\n");
  if(this->getLength() < rhs.getLength())
    minSize = this->getLength();
  else
    minSize = rhs.getLength();

  for(i = 0; i < minSize; i++) //SEGFAULT from accessing rhs.number[0]
      this->modifyNumber(this->number[i] + rhs.number[i], i);

  if(this->getLength() < rhs.getLength()){
      for(;i < rhs.getLength(); i++)
          this->modifyNumber(rhs.number[i], i); 
    }
  else{
      for(;i < this->getLength(); i++)
          this->modifyNumber(this->number[i], i);
    }
  return *this;
}

const Bcd& Bcd::operator +(const Bcd &rhs) const
{
  return Bcd(*this) += rhs;
}

Bcd::Bcd(const Bcd &num)
{
  length = num.length;
  size = num.size;
  //allocate memory for number
  number = new char[length];
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      number[i] = num.number[i];
}
```

Comment: What does your `Bcd::~Bcd`, `Bcd::Bcd(const Bcd&)` look like?

Comment: _"The important bits of the .c file is here:"_ Ahem not really. Also why do you call a C++ file `.c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly how it should happen. It is probably more correct to say that it is not temporary `b1 + b2` that gets destroyed, it is temporary `Bcd(*this) += rhs` inside your implementation of binary `+` that gets destroyed.

Your implementation of `+`

```
const Bcd& Bcd::operator +(const Bcd &rhs) const
{
  return Bcd(*this) += rhs;
}
```

attempts to return a reference bound to a temporary. The temporary gets destroyed before the function exits, the reference remains hanging. The caller receives a "dead" reference. The behavior is undefined.

This is *not* one of the contexts in which the lifetime of a temporary gets extended by a reference attached to it.

You cannot return a reference from your binary `+`. You simply don't have anything to return a reference to. Instead, return by value

```
Bcd Bcd::operator +(const Bcd &rhs) const
{
  return Bcd(*this) += rhs;
}
```

This implementation will indeed return a temporary that will serve as `b1 + b2`. And that temporary will not be destroyed prematurely.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that operator+ should return a copy of the object, not a reference. I think your code creates a temporary and returns its reference, which is a big NO.

Your compiler should have warned you. If using GCC use -W -Wall every time. It will help a lot.

Now that is weird. I tested this with my GCC and I only get the warning if I compile with -O2 or -O3 optimization on.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`